# Replace commas in a form with jquery-validate

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Let's insert 5 numerical values >0 using the form:

```
    <label for="altezza">Inserisci la tua altezza (in cm)</label>
    <input type="text" name="altezza" id="altezza" value="" />

    <label for="peso">Inserisci il tuo peso (in kg)</label>
    <input type="text" name="peso" id="peso" value="" />

    <label for="vita">Inserisci la misura della tua vita (in cm)</label>
    <input type="text" name="vita" id="vita" value="" />

        <label for="fianchi">Inserisci la misura dei tuoi fianchi (in cm)</label>
    <input type="text" name="fianchi" id="fianchi" value="" />

        <label for="collo">Inserisci la misura del tuo collo (in cm)</label>
    <input type="text" name="collo" id="collo" value="" />

    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Invia" />
```

Validator:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#formpeso").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            altezza: {min:1, required: true},
            peso: {min:1, required: true},
            vita: {min:1, required: true},
            fianchi: {min:1, required: true},
            collo: {min:1, required: true},
        },
        messages: {
            altezza: "Non hai compilato il campo!<br />",
            peso: "Non hai compilato il campo!<br />",
            vita: "Non hai compilato il campo!<br />",
            fianchi: "Non hai compilato il campo!<br />",
            collo: "Non hai compilato il campo!<br />",

        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.post('calcolatore2.php', $("#formpeso").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#results').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Any way to let the user insert values with a comma instead of a "." decimal separator, and have the validator replace those commas?
Thanks

Comment: I don't believe you'd want the validator to do such a thing.  Just write a separate function to replace commas that's triggered on mouse out or blur of that particular field.  Otherwise, you would just use the validator to alert the visitor to use periods instead of commas.

Comment: I thought there was a simpler way to do it without having to write a separate function. Anyway this (activated "onkeyup") did the trick `function commadot(that) {
if (that.value.indexOf(",") >= 0) {
that.value = that.value.replace(/\,/g,".");
}
}`

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate function, like mentioned by Sparky672, like this:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    $('input').not('#submit').each(function(){
         $(this).val($(this).val().replace(',','.'));                 
    });
});
```